# Removable disk, hybrid GPT/MBR

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, partitioning, gpt

I'm trying to set up a USB HD with GPT so that partition 1 is accessible under all versions of Windows.

Sounds easy, right? (In particular, I'm not trying to *boot* Windows. I just want to plug in a disk and have it see the contents.)

Well, if you just write a normal GPT, everything works fine under Windows 7. But of course, Windows XP doesn't know anything about GPT, and just sees the protective MBR.

This was what I was expecting. So I copied the sector numbers of partition 1 into the MBR. Sure enough, Windows XP now sees that partition just fine.

The problem is... Windows 7 now behaves *very* strangely. It now only sees the entries in the MBR (which I don't really mind), and it doesn't auto-mount the partition (which is unacceptable).

Weirder still, if I manually assign a drive letter to the partition, it's readable and everything. But when I unplug the disk, the drive letter is *still there!* And it's now impossible to remove it, because it no longer appears in Disk Management.

Does anybody know what magic voodoo I need to do to make the disk "just work" in all versions of Windows from XP onwards? (I haven't actually tested with Vista yet, but I imagine it probably behaves similarly to Win7.)

(One obvious possibility is to just remove GPT. But I really don't want to do that...)

I have already tested and confirmed that the presence or absence of a type EE partition in the MBR appears to make no difference to Windows.

Comment: What keeps you away from MBR? GPT was introduced for bigger disks (above 1TB) and its the only reason why you should force it.

Comment: I want to use GUIDs to identify which disk it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MBR. As you've discovered, Windows XP and earlier don't understand GPT. The method you've used to try to get around this limitation is essentially to re-create an ugly and dangerous hack known as a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) although I suspect you're doing it in a somewhat different way that's causing problems for Windows 7. (Ordinarily, Windows Vista through 8.1 see the MBR side of a "conventional" hybrid MBR.) I urge you to read the linked-to page, which describes hybrid MBRs, including their drawbacks, in some detail.

Note that because Windows Vista and later treat hybrid MBR disks as conventional MBR disks, there's *no advantage* to using them in a Windows-only environment. They are limiting and dangerous, though, so you'll end up with all of the drawbacks and none of the benefits of a hybrid MBR.

The only other solution I'm aware of is to use a GPT driver for pre-Vista versions of Windows. Such things exist for Windows XP, although I don't have any URLs offhand. I don't know if such a driver exists for Windows Me or earlier. Of course, such a driver would have to be pre-installed on any computer with which you want to use it, which might or might not be a deal-breaker for you.

Overall, you're best off using MBR in your situation. If you need to uniquely identify a partition, try using the volume label for that.

Comment: All I did was `sgdisk -h=1 /dev/sdb`. I thought that would work. And while it does work for XP, it makes Win7 behave strangely, for no reason that I can discover...

Comment: Windows 7 *should* work OK with a hybrid MBR created by `sgdisk`; however, as I said, a hybrid MBR is a *dangerous hack.* It *violates* the GPT standard, so there's no guarantee that it will work with anything. Avoid hybrid MBRs unless they're absolutely necessary. Even if it worked the way it normally does, as I said, you'd get *no benefits* from a GPT with hybrid MBR. Your stated reason for wanting to use GPT in the first place is a bit vague, so it's difficult to suggest a way to do what you want.

Comment: I admit defeat. I'm going to have to completely redesign my software now. :-(